# Can we use one CA to revoke certificates generated by another CA?

Tags: tls, openssl, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation, crl

I have a hierarchy of certificates which contains:

- `root-cert`

  - `server1-CA` (issued from `root-CA`)

    - `client1-cert` (issued from `server1-CA`)
  - `server2-CA` (issued from `root-CA`)

    - `client2-cert` (issued from `servier2-CA`)

I need to generate one CRL file and use it in both `server1` and `server2` (or in other servers).
Can I revoke client certificates using `root-CA` (to have a unique CRL file)? Or is there a way to merge multiple CRL files ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, not in practice.**

No, you can't. CA can revoke certificates it signed/issued only. There are a number of reasons for this choice. Although, [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) supports delegated revocation authorities (through registering it in the [`Issuing Distribution Point`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-5.2.5) CRL extension), in practice it is not implemented by crypto clients in most cases.

One simple example: two CAs issued certificate with matching serial number (serial number uniqueness must be provided for each separate CA key, technically, two CAs may have certs with the same serial number) and you revoke it. The question: which certificate did you revoke?

The only thing you can do is to revoke subordinate CA certificate (effectively revoking all certificates down in path of that subordinate CA).

Comment: The problem is if I use a unique CRL file in one server, I will have SSLHandshakeException between the server and another non-revoked certificate issued from different serverCA. 
I get this message : "First cause: Could not determine revocation status"

Comment: this means that some CRLs are missing or `CRL Distribution Points` certificate extension is configured incorrectly.

Comment: I didn't configure any CRL Distribution Points, can you please show me how to configure it ?

Comment: That's problem if you dodn't. I don't know what software you use to run CA servers, but I would suggest to consult with CA server documentation.

Comment: I'm using openssl.

Comment: OpenSSL is more a cryptography library/framework and may be used as a crypto platform for CA, but not work as a CA. I would suggest to look at CA software solutions that would handle most of CA-related tasks. For Linux I would suggest to take a loot at EJBCA, for Windows -- ADCS (Active Directory Certificate Services).

Comment: @Crypt32 OpenSSL is a good solution for an offline root CA. For the root CA all you're doing is issuing/revoking the next level CAs' certificates. It's the _subordinate_ CA that needs all the tools.