# How do I use crlDistributionPoints with keytool?

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl, java, certificate-revocation, crl

I'm using the [Java `keytool` command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) to generate keystores and openssl to revoke certificate and generate CRL.
However I need to configure crlDistributionPoints extension as described in the [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.13).

So is there a way to configure Distribution Points with keytool ?

Comment: As I mentioned in another thread (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148043/can-we-use-one-ca-to-revoke-certificates-generated-by-another-ca), you really should get standard CA software, instead of using low-level tools. What I get from practice, such custom and hand-made configurations will quickly become unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, it is not documented in the oracle documentation but it exists :

the extension is `-ext crl` .

I hope that it will help someone.

Comment: Is this the same as "-ext 2.5.29.31"?

Comment: I didn't try with OID, but I know that 2.5.29.31 is the OID of crlDistributionPoints.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing here:
Use raw [OID 2.5.29.31](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=2.5.29.31&action=display) with the generic [`-ext` parameter](https://archive.is/7C6GY#selection-1133.0-1193.1).

But like Crypt32 said: This is terrible to manage.